# Recreate container on exit in k8s

Tags: kubernetes

I have a Deployment in k8s which contains a single container, which exits when it completes its work. By default, k8s then restarts the container.

I would like to recreate the container (or the whole Pod) on exit instead. The work involves a number of temporary files and other changes in the container, which should be discarded when it exits and a fresh container created from the image.

How can I configure the Deployment (or another workload) so that an exited container is either recreated, or causes the whole pod to exit and be recreated?

There is a `restartPolicy` setting, but it's forced to `Always` for Deployments. There appears to be a `maxRetries` setting, but I can't find the documentation or any examples for it. I'm not sure what else to search for.

Comment: do you want to recreate pod when update a new image ?

Comment: Could you please explain what is the difference between restarting and recreating a container?

Comment: restart container meaning , we just restart the existing container,  image of container doesnot  change, recreate container  , image of container shoud be changed, terminate all pods and create  a new one

Comment: When a container restarts, all the files that it created are still there. I want the conteiner to be removed and a new one started in its place (in the same pod or a new one).

Comment: The image will normally be unchanged; the process running in the container completes an item off an external queue, then terminates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/job/) API Object may help. If you use `restartPolicy=Never` in a `Job` then the `Pods` managed by the `Job` will restart each time the process running in the `Pod`'s container exits with error code. Using `restartPolicy=Always` will only restart/recreate the container without recreating the `pod`.

In addition, when a container restart in Kubernetes, it means it is re-created.: all the file created in the container are removed, except the ones which where created on attached persistent storage (for example PersistenceVolume). There is no equivalent to `docker start/stop` in Kubernetes.

Comment: How would I set a Job to restart indefinitely? Is there a value that means "infinite completions"? Otherwise I'd need to use some hack like setting completions to 999999, or making sure the container never exits successfully?

Comment: If the container never exits successfully it should work. However this is a hack and I would not recommend it on production platform, this would make maintenance difficult.

Comment: At that point, setting completions to 999999 would be the smaller hack, but still a hack...

Comment: Looks like nobody has a better answer than "Job with completions=999999999" so I guess I'll go with that